# Why my getElementsByTagName returns an empty NodeList?

Tags: javascript

This is my code:

```
<html>

<h1 id="hg">
    <h2>11</h2>
    <h2>22</h2>
    <h2>33</h2>
</h1>

<script>
    var h = document.getElementById("hg").getElementsByTagName("h2");
    alert(h.length);
</script>

</html>
```

I have looked up the manual, it seems that `getElementById` returns an `HTMLHeadingElement` in this case, and it inherits the method `getElementsByTagName` from `Element`. I expect to get a `3` as the value of `h.length`, but instead I get `0`. What's wrong with it?

Comment: It's because your HTML is invalid. Headings cannot sit inside another heading. If you check your page in a DOM inspector such as Firebug you'll see the actual HTML being rendered is quite different to that you have written.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You'll find that a [`<h1>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/h1.html) cannot contain *another* heading (the only valid content of an `h1`, and other headings, is [phrasing content](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/terminology.html#phrasing-content), which restricts content to, very simplistically, in-line elements and text), therefore when the browser constructs the DOM it moves the `h2` elements *outside* of the `h1`, which prevents them being found, by the DOM, inside the `h1`.

In Chrome, your HTML is reorganised to the following (and, I *presume*, similarly rearranged in other browsers):

```
<h1 id="hg"></h1>
<h2>11</h2>
<h2>22</h2>
<h2>33</h2>
```

This rescuing of the DOM to maintain validity is why we should, as developers, *always* strive to create valid HTML: because the automatic corrections made by browsers are undocumented and unpredictable (prior to HTML 5, which I think documents how error recovery should proceed).

Incidentally, this sounds very similar to the use-case presented for the [`<hgroup>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/hgroup.html#hgroup) element (which seems to be in the process of being dropped from the spec). Given, however, that you appear to be presenting a list of contents I'd suggest enclosing the `<h2>` elements in an `<ol>` and semantically grouping them that way:

```
<ol id="contents">
    <li><h2>11</h2></li>
    <li><h2>22</h2></li>
    <li><h2>33</h2></li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to change your html to this for example:

```
<div id="hg">
    <h2>11</h2>
    <h2>22</h2>
    <h2>33</h2>
</div>
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/85hPn/)